# Preview Azure Blob binary file in html

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I  have   uploaded   Binary   file   to  Azure   blob.now  i  want  to   display   All binary   file   actual   Content  on  html  like  if orignal  file  was  with extension  .pdf  or  .jpg  i  want  to   display  this  on  html  page  .

But   Azure  Blob  only   return  Binary   File .how  i  will   achieve   this

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to show the contents of the blob in the web page itself, like in a text area or something like that. Correct?

Comment: yes,  if  i  able  to   Display  Containt  of   blob  in  html   i  am   good  with  it